# How to encrypt xml file by boost property_tree?

Tags: c++, xml, encryption, boost

Now I want to generate one encrypted XML file through `Boost ptree`.

```
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree   pt;

    pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Guid", m_Guid);
    pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.CustomerId", m_CustomerId);
    pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Name", m_Name);
    pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Version", m_version);

    write_xml(licenseFileName, pt);
```

I want to encrypt the whole xml file before `write_xml()` is called. Through reading the codes of `write_xml`, I know the xml nodes are read from ptree one by one, then write them into `fstream` immediately one by one. **Is there any way to get the whole xml data stream before write it to file?** so that I can encrypt the whole data stream, then write them to file.

Currently, My solution is that reread this xml file after created by `write_xml`, then write it back after encrypting the xml content.

Comment: So write it to an `std::ostringstream` using the alternate [`write_xml`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/xml_parser/write_xml_id987659.html), then encrypt the result and dump *that* to disk.

Comment: You mean write the `pt` to `ostringstream`?

Comment: Yes, then pull the result from the `.str()` method of your ossencrypt the bits, and dump it to your file. That's pretty much it. I'm not thrilled with the data copying, and  I wanted to see if there was a way for your to use the interprocess vector stream or buffered stream from boost for this, but alas I don't think there is (or someone a lot more savvy in boost than I may show you how). I know a `std::ostringstream` will work, however.

Comment: I want to encrypt the whole element such as `<Guid>123</Guid>`, I do not know how to get the whole xml element tree from `ptree`.

Comment: Thats the point of `write_xml`. It will dump the entire ptree as XML into the target stream. Once there, you can encrypt the whole file in one shot and send it to your *actual* target (a disk file). If it is possible to explain this in anymore detail, I can't see how. Sry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commenters suggested this:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
write_xml(oss, pt);

// now you can encrypt
std::string plain_text = oss.str();
```

Now you can encrypt the plaintext and write the ciphertext to a file

Comment: +1 Yup, that's spot-on what I was trying to say (should have just written the code, would have been a lot fewer keystrokes).

Comment: @WhozCraig I was gonna point to an approach with custom streambuf but I thought better of it